# MonoTouch.Dialog cannot get the values on textfields

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have the following code

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UINavigationController _navigationController = new UINavigationController();

        public enum PrivacySetting { always, never, friends };

        LogInViewModel _login;

        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            _login = new LogInViewModel
            {
                Privacy = PrivacySetting.always
            };

            var _loginbindingcontext = new BindingContext(this, _login, "Login");
            var dialogcontroller = new DialogViewController(_loginbindingcontext.Root);

            _navigationController.PushViewController(dialogcontroller, true);

            window.AddSubview(_navigationController.View);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }

        // This method is required in iPhoneOS 3.0
        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
        }

        public class LogInViewModel
        {

            [Section("Credentials")]

            [Entry("Username")]
            public string login;

            [Caption("Password"), Password("Password")]
            public string password;

            [Section("Privacy")]

            [Caption("Show Name")]
            public PrivacySetting Privacy;

            [Section ("Tap to Console")]
            [OnTap ("tapme")]
            public string TapMe;
        }

        public void tapme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_login.login);    
        }
    }
```

i run the application then i fill in the textfields but when i tap on TapMe i get a null value, so how can i retrieve values on textfields using monotouch.dialog?

Comment: does that code even compile properly.. `_login` is not even available in the `tapme()` function how are you getting the login property

Comment: mmmm, it will compile because LogInViewModel _login; its a "Global" variable on AppDelegate class

Comment: Yes it compiles, but im not able to get the values, i always get a Null :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first call Fetch() on the binding context, like this:

```
public void tapme()
{
            _loginbindingcontext.Fetch();
            Console.WriteLine(_login.login);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_loginbindingcontext.Fetch();
```

This will populate the `LogInViewModel` with the values from the Elements in the `DialogViewController`.

You will need to keep a reference in your `ViewModel` for the `BindingContext` so that you can call `Fetch()`.

Alternatively, you can check out my project on GitHub MonoTouch.MVVM which makes these kinds of things easier. Its not done yet and its only a proof of concept but I am actively working on it. https://github.com/RobertKozak/MonoTouch.MVVM

Comment: Do you have any blog where MVVM its documented?

Comment: Not yet. But I will. I have some more work to do on it first before I start documenting it. The design is going thru some changes so I don't want to document it yet until it stabilizes. I'll have a big update in the next couple of weeks.